# Symfony gives wrong date after doctrine request

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

Strangest thing today, I make a doctrine request to get an Order from a precise date. But when I dump the date, I get a different date than the one in the database, I get the day after.

From doctrine, with my request `$order = $em->getRepository(Order::class)->findOrderByDate()` I get the order I want. I double check in the database, the order ID has the good date **16-12-2022**.

But then if I dump my order date, `dump($order->getDate())` I get the following date **17-12-2022**.
`DateTime @1671274800 {#1248 date: 2022-12-17 12:00:00.0 Europe/Berlin (+01:00) }`

If I manually change the time in the database, I still get the wrong date, but the time is correctly changed. (That would confirm that I interact with the right object)

I am on php 8.1.13, symfony 6.1.8.
The issue is the same on my PC or in the prod server.

What is happening here ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hint: Which DBMS do you use? If it supports timezoned datetime/timestamp columns, that could be well be the cause. Check the timezone of a server, database server and PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the culprit.
A function was making an API call with these lines :

```
$dateStart = $order->getDate();
...
$startDate->modify('+1 day');
```

I didn't think the date was passed by reference when you use the getter from the Order object.

If anyone knows more about the subject or have any link, I sure would take a look.